# How to reduce the if else if ladder code length which is displaying the textviews based on the text inside the if condition

Tags: android, android-studio, textview

i am new to Android Development.I have created an applicaiton which will display the corresponding textview on clicking a textview.

For that i have given  a if-else-if ladder condition statement to display the textview. Since i have lot of textviews(around 100), while building the project android studio is saying CODE IS TOO LONG.

How to solve this issue. Is it possible to use the MAP to iterate through the textview IDS?

Please help me.

```
 public void click(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fam:
            // check if a child is set to a specific String
            String toSearchFor = "badaatext";
            boolean found = false;
            ArrayList<View> allViewsWithinMyTopView = getAllChildren(findViewById(R.id.linear));
            for (View child : allViewsWithinMyTopView) {
                if (child instanceof TextView) {
                    TextView childTextView = (TextView) child;
                    int intName = childTextView.getId();
                    System.out.println("The Child TextView is : " + childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intName));
                    if (childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intName).startsWith("badaatext")) {
                        found = true;
                        System.out.println("The text is foudn inside the layout");
                        System.out.println("And the Textview ID is :" + childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intName));
                        childTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        String BadaaString = childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intchildName);
                        System.out.println("The Big TextView is : " + BadaaString);
                        String ChotaString = BadaaString.substring(9, 12);
                        System.out.println("The Small Textview is : " + ChotaString);
                        if (ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("rel")) {
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rel);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("nam")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nam);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("mom")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mom);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("dad")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dad);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("elb")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.elb);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("els")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.els);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("yos")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yos);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("sil")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sil);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("yob")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yob);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("hus")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hus);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("wif")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wif);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("fre")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fre);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("tea")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tea);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("ser")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ser);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("mai")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mai);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("wom")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wom);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("stm")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stm);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("man")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.man);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("boy")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.boy);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gir")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gir);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gue")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gue);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("cus")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cus);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("hoi")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hoi);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gif")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gif);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("son")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.son);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("dau")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dau);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gpa")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gpa);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gma")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gma);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gdp")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gdp);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gdm")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gdm);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("und")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.und);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("aud")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aud);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("maa")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.maa);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("mam")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mam);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("mad")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mad);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("ata")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ata);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("fla")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fla);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("mla")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mla);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("sod")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sod);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("gru")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gru);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("som")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.som);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("grm")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.grm);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("unp")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.unp);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else if(ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("aup")){
                            //Display the Small TextView:
                            TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aup);
                            Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("No Matches found");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                //fail("Text '" + The text is not available in the layout");
                System.out.println("The TextView is not present inside the layout");
            }


            //Make the Clicked View to be Invisible
            TextView Engfam = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fam);
            Engfam.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //Adding the corresponding dynamic textview
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            /* Add textview 1 */
            TextView textViewFamily = new TextView(lessonSix.this);
//            textView1.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams textviewLayoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(textViewFamily, 100,600, 2, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);

            textviewLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 9, 0, 0);
//                linearLayout.addView(textView1, 1, textviewLayoutParams);
            textViewFamily.setId(R.id.badaatextFam);
            textViewFamily.setLayoutParams(textviewLayoutParams);
            textViewFamily.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapelineinsideroundedrect
 );
textViewFamily.setText("FAMILY - குடும்பம்");
            textViewFamily.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER);
            textViewFamily.setTextSize(20);
            textViewFamily.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            textViewFamily.setPadding(0, 25, 0, 25);
            textViewFamily.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout.addView(textViewFamily, 1);
            break;

 case R.id.gir:

            // check if a child is set to a specific String
            found = false;
            ArrayList<View> allViewsWithinMyTopView21 = getAllChildren(findViewById(R.id.linear));
            for (View child : allViewsWithinMyTopView21) {
                if (child instanceof TextView) {
                    childTextView = (TextView) child;
                    intchildName = childTextView.getId();
                    System.out.println("The Child TextView is : " + childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intchildName));
                    if (childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intchildName).startsWith("badaatext")) {
                        found = true;
                        System.out.println("The text is foudn inside the layout");
                        System.out.println("And the Textview ID is :" + childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intchildName));
                        childTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        String BadaaString = childTextView.getResources().getResourceEntryName(intchildName);
                        System.out.println("The Big TextView is : " + BadaaString);
                        String ChotaString = BadaaString.substring(9, 12);
                        System.out.println("The Small Textview is : " + ChotaString);
//if (ChotaString.equalsIgnoreCase("fam")) {
// //Display the Small TextView:
// TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fam);
//Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//}
       int textViewId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(ChotaString, "id", context.getPackageName());
                        TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
                        Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }

                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                //fail("Text '" + The text is not available in the layout");
                System.out.println("The TextView is not present inside the layout");
            }
            //Make the Clicked View to be Invisible
            TextView Enggir = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gir);
            Enggir.setVisibility(View.GONE);


            //Adding the corresponding dynamic textview
            LinearLayout linearLayout21 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
            linearLayout21.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            /* Add textview 1 */
            TextView textViewGirl = new TextView(lessonSix.this);
//textView1.setLayoutParams(new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
LinearLayout.LayoutParams textviewLayoutParams21 = new 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            TextViewCompat.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(textViewGirl, 100,600, 2, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
            textviewLayoutParams21.setMargins(0, 9, 0, 0);
//linearLayout.addView(textView1, 1, textviewLayoutParams);s
            textViewGirl.setId(R.id.badaatextGir);
            textViewGirl.setLayoutParams(textviewLayoutParams21);
            textViewGirl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapelineinsideroundedrect);
            textViewGirl.setText("GIRL - சிறுமி");
            textViewGirl.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER);
            textViewGirl.setTextSize(20);
            textViewGirl.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            textViewGirl.setPadding(0, 25, 0, 25);
            textViewGirl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            linearLayout21.addView(textViewGirl, 40);
            break;
```

The Relevant XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue"
tools:context=".lessonSix">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/badaatextOne"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="130dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="5dp"-->
        <!--android:paddingTop="25dp"-->
        <!--android:background="@drawable/shapelineinsideroundedrect"-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fam"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shaperoundedcornerrect"
            android:text="FAMILY"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="OnClick" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shaperoundedcornerrect"
            android:text="RELATION"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gir"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/shaperoundedcornerrect"
            android:text="GIRL"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="click"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dip"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding the Exception : 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.seekho.noushad.dictionary, PID: 30013
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException  Application terminated.

```
New Log(Exception):
```

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.seekho.noushad.dictionary, PID: 24918
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714) 
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                      at com.seekho.noushad.dictionary.lessonSix.click(lessonSix.java:4893)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19923) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5401) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:919) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:714) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 24918 SIG: 9
Application terminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `TextView` Id by it's name. Since your `if()` condifion string equals to the name of the `TextView`, you can use:

```
int textViewId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(ChotaString, "id", context.getPackageName());
TextView Engtxt1 = (TextView) findViewById(textViewId);
Engtxt1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

instead of whole your `if(){}else{}`

Comment: Have you seen the latest log that i have attached

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference` the context is null. Show how you initialized it.

Comment: public class lessonSix extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    ViewGroup viewGroup;
    public Intent intent;
    boolean found;
    TextView Engtxt;
    TextView childTextView;
    int intchildName;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson_six);

Comment: I don't see you have initialized `context`. Since your class is Activity, you can use `this` instead of `context`

Comment: i used the "this" instead of "context" but got the exception :   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
                      at com.seekho.noushad.dictionary.lessonSix.click(lessonSix.java:4895)

Answer (score -1):

you  can use switch instead of if else if ladder . or either map but in map you need to give a key for each value.

Comment: But for swich statement also i have to use lot of case as per the count of my textview id